# Are AMD Drivers Required?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, debian, amd-radeon, amd-catalyst

I just bought a graphics card, specifically [this one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814202099). It's AMD-made.
I've never done much on the hardware side of my PC. I would like to know:
Do I really *need* AMD Catalyst *(or whatever)* drivers?

Will it work without drivers?
What difference does it make if I do or don't install them?

Thanks,
*ItsBobberson*

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 Enterprise and possibly Debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the proprietary graphics driver makes a big difference in performance in Linux compared to using the built-in open source graphics driver. In one of your questions you mentioned that you are running Ubuntu. In Ubuntu run the following command from the terminal to identify the recommended proprietary graphics drivers to install:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Then you can install it with the usual `sudo apt-get install` command. You can also install the recommend proprietary graphics driver automatically with the following command:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

`sudo ubuntu-drivers install` installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies.

Comment: Congratulation Sir for guessing what is the OS with NO mention in tags or user's question... :-D